# How to solve TF_NAN_INPUT

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm quite new to vslam and I was wondering if anyone who could help me with this problem. When I try to get live data using a bumblebee2 camera and rviz, the blue lines get all broken and scattered in weird places. like this: [image: image description]

I suspect the following error message below(it was reported in my rviz window) will show what is responsible for this, but I cannot interpret where the error is. Thanks for the help.

```
[ERROR] [1306481857.228246721]: TF_NAN_INPUT: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "/visual_odom" from authority "/bumblebee2/stereo_vslam_node" because of a nan value in the transform (nan nan nan) (-nan nan nan -nan)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10080/how-to-solve-tf_nan_input/) by [ccm](https://answers.ros.org/users/604/ccm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 226 on 2011-05-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) on 2011-05-27**:
I'd recommend to change the title to something like "How to solve TF_NAN_INPUT".  I fail  to see how your question is related to rosbag record.

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2011-05-27**:
I got this message from several nodes while calling the tf static_transform_publisher (with a all zero transform, needed for move_base)  in a bash. Putting the same call as a node in the move_base launch file kept the error away, nevertheless I do not understand it.

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2011-05-26**:
It would help if you post exactly what you're running - any relevant launch files or commands. Are there any other errors or warnings in the console or the logs? Also the title doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question - consider renaming, "TF_NAN_INPUT in vslam" for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

TF_NAN_INPUT usually is caused by invalid quaternions being sent.  You will need to debug the program sending the quaternions.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-05-15**:
the same problem

I am using this:

self._tfpub.sendTransform((object_tf), tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0, 0, 0), rospy.Time.now(), tf_id, frame)

please help me

thank you in advance

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-05-15**:
outpot:

Error:   TF_NAN_INPUT: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "person_0" from authority "/image_converter" because of a nan value in the transform (nan -nan -nan) (0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000)
at line 244 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-indigo-tf2-0.5.20/src/buffer_core.cpp

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2020-08-24**:
I'm facing this issue while running hector_mapping: https://answers.ros.org/question/360033/hector-mapping-tf-issue-tf_nan_input-and-tf_denormalized_quaternion/
What should I do?